# How can I implement a custom animated transition between two Flutter screens using the PageRouteBuilder and Hero widget?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm working on a Flutter application and want to implement a custom animated transition between two screens or pages using the PageRouteBuilder and Hero widget. I've read the official documentation, but I'm still having trouble achieving the desired transition effect. I want to create a smooth and visually appealing transition where a widget on one screen 'heroically' transforms into a matching widget on the second screen. How can I achieve this effect and what are some best practices?

Created a PageRouteBuilder to handle the navigation between the two screens.
Used the Hero widget to wrap the widgets I want to animate between the screens.
Specified unique tag properties for the Hero widgets on both screens.